# spring jpa integration error

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jpa

I have problem with spring jpa integration. I write simple app and have such entity element

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "NEWS")
public class News{
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "AUTO_INCREMENT", name = "sequence")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "sequence", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "NEWSTITLE", nullable = false)
    private String newsTitle;
    @Column(name = "NEWSDATE", nullable = false)
    private Date newsDate;
    @Column(name = "BRIEF", nullable = false)
    private String brief;
    @Column(name = "CONTENT", nullable = false)
    private String content;
    private String date;
```

and this is my spring config

```
    <bean id="dataSource"
            class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver.manager}" />
            <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
            <property name="username" value="${jdbc.login}" />
            <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
        </bean>
   <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.epam.newsmanagement.entity"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="database" value="ORACLE" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaDao" class="com.epam.newsmanagementserver.dao.JPANewsDao">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
```

while deploying in tomcat I get this error:

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in Ser
vletContext resource [/WEB-INF/jpa-configuration.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframewor
k.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'packagesToScan' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalCont
ainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Bean property 'packagesToScan' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the par
ameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'packagesToScan' of bean class [org.spri
ngframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Bean property 'packagesToScan' is not writable or has an invali
d setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:751)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:608)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:49)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:74)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:57)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowire
CapableBeanFactory.java:970)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapable
BeanFactory.java:729)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBe
anFactory.java:416)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:245)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.
java:141)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:242)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:156)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBean
Factory.java:287)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:348)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractRefreshableWebAp
plicationContext.java:156)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:246)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:184)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:49)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1655)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

looking trow the internet I find that to solve this problem we need to use spring version 3.1 and newer. But **I use spring version 3.2.3** and get this error. 
Please help(

**UPDATE**

@Avi find that Spring ORM version 3.2.3 has not method setPackagesToScan. So I change version to 3.2.0 and I find such mehod in this version. but after start I have the same error

Comment: Are you sure there is no conflict in your classpath and that you are really using a `spring-orm` version greater than 3.0?

Comment: @mabbas, I use maven and in pom.xml I specify spring-orm version 3.2.3.RELEASE. And when I package my web-app into war file I look into it's lib folder and didn't find any libraries that may be conflict with each other

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you're trying to set a property that doesn't exist. The class `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` has no setter named `setPackagesToScan` and yet you try to set such property.

Comment: but when I use version 3.2.0 this method was. So may be know how can I specify packages where jpa must search my annotated entity classes now?

Answer (score 1):

Check your dependencies.

[Documentation setPackagesToScan:](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.html#setPackagesToScan%28java.lang.String...%29)

> **NOTE: Only applied if no external PersistenceUnitManager specified.**

Example dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${org.hibernate-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-data-jpa-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql-version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your web.xml looks something like this.

```
<web-app>
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
    classpath:/beans.xml,       
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Filter and FilterMapping tags are removed from this example. Make sure you have them..

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you look for `org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`  api

there is no property like packageForScan  That's why its giving error  you can use component scan  in your spring.xml for giving your package containg entity

Container will automatically scan entity than